# Conditional formatting SharePoint list issue with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json

I am trying to use JSON code on SharePoint list - works fine with 2 conditions(green,red) but I am not able to add additional condition, third with yellow...not sure how it should look.

workable:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now - 7776000000 ,'green', (if(@currentField >= @now - 604800000, '#ffa59b','red'))"
  }
}
```

I am trying to add "yellow now - 4800000"

## Update

We need 2 colors - green and red. Red should be for todays date and within range of 30 days from today in the past. Rest in green - both ways - ahead and in the past. Example : Today is the 10.5 that should be in red, 30 days back still in red. Above 30 days in the past Green and Tomorrow continuously green.

Comment: Please elaborate your required color conditions in question. I mean when you need green, red or yellow color.

Comment: Ok so there is completely different condition now - We need 2 colors - green and red. Red should be for todays date and within range of 30 days from today in the past. Rest in green - both ways - ahead and in the past. Example : Today is the 10.5 that should be in red, 30 days back still in red. Above 30 days in the past Green and Tomorrow continuously green.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly had it! Just need to continue nesting additional `if` statements in the else operand spot:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now - 7776000000 ,'green', if(@currentField >= @now - 604800000, '#ffa59b', if(@currentField >= @now - 4800000,'yellow','red')))"
  }
}
```

Comment: HI Chris! Thanks for the code but when I paste it to my column I receive error: Error saving column format: {"d": {"CustomFormatter": "{\"$schema\":\"https:\u002F\u002Fdeveloper.microsoft.com\u002Fjson-schemas\u002Fsp\u002Fv2\u002Fcolumn-formatting.schema.json\",\"elmType\":\"div\",\"txtContent\":\"@currentField\",\"style\":{\"background-color\":\"=if(currentField >= now - 7776000000 ,'green', if(currentField >= now - 604800000, '#ffa59b', if(currentField >= now - 4800000,'yellow','red')))\"}}", "Id": ""}}
Switch to design mode
This formatting JSON will be discarded

Comment: I removed @ because it was blocking me...

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. What you pasted in the comments looks to be escaped and won't work in that format. Is that just a comments issue or is that the actual format text you are trying to use? This format requires you to use the column menu > _Column settings_ > _Format this column_ and then choose **Advanced Mode** to paste the code above exactly as it's written. Then hit save. If you are getting the design mode message then you are trying to switch to the wizard which will not work with this custom format.

Comment: Ok so there is completely different condition now - We need 2 colors - green and red. Red should be for todays date and within range of 30 days from today in the past. Rest in green - both ways - ahead and in the past. Example : Today is the 10.5 that should be in red, 30 days back still in red. Above 30 days in the past Green and Tomorrow continuously green.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
      "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now && (@currentField) >= Number(@now - 2592000000) ,'red','green')"
    }
  }
```